# How do i overwrite everything inside a div except for one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like below

```
<div id="contributors_div">
     <div id="arrow-up"></div>
</div>
```

I am populating `contributors_div` with some text(data) on different anchor clicks. My `<div id="arrow-up"></div>` has image of an arrow which has to be shown.

Below is how i am populating the div (or say overwriting)

```
var ul_data = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < CONTRIBUTORS.length; i++) {
    ul_data = ul_data + "<li><h3>" + CONTRIBUTORS[i] + "</h3></li>";
}
$("#contributors_div").html(ul_data);
```

But this is removing the arrow as well. When i use`append`, my old data also gets appended which is not as desired. Can anyone tell me the correct way.
Thanks

Comment: can you add your desired html output?

Comment: please note it is advised to actually have a <ul/> tag to put the <li/> tags inside. and it might solve you the original problem as well.

Comment: @Oded is correct, your rendered html is not valid here

Comment: even if i use <ul> tags, that won't solve my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleaner way would be, IMO, to insert a container `<ul></ul>` alongside the arrow-up and fill/empty it.

```
<div id="contributors_div">
     <ul></ul>
     <div id="arrow-up"></div>
</div>
```

And then

```
$('#contributors_div ul').html(ul_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$("#contributors_div *:not(#arrow-up)").remove();
```

and then `append()`...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/eQHeS/)

(Probably you should use arrow-up as a class and not and ID, I guess it is not the only arrow on the whole page)

Answer (score 1):

Given that li elements are supposed to belong to an ol or ul element I'd update your structure to this:

```
<div id="contributors_div">
     <ul></ul>
     <div id="arrow-up"></div>
</div>
```

And then you could say:

```
$("#contributors_div ul").html(ul_data);
```

...to just update the content of the list. (Of course you can give the ul an id or class if needed, but it would work without it.)

But to answer your question more literally, you can temporarily remove the arrow with the [`.detach()` method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), and then `.append()` or [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) it back after making the other change:

```
var $arrowUp = $("#arrow-up").detach();
var ul_data = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < CONTRIBUTORS.length; i++) {
    ul_data = ul_data + "<li><h3>" + CONTRIBUTORS[i] + "</h3></li>";
}
$("#contributors_div").html(ul_data)
                      .append($arrowUp);
```

Comment: detach() method is something new for me. Will definitely try that as well. Although the answer i accepted did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way would be like the below(though its a bit hacky!)

```
<div id="contributors_div">
 </div>
```

and the jquery part would be

`$("#contributors_div").html("<div id=\"arrow-up\"></div>");
$("#contributors_div").append(ul_data);`

Comment: this way you lose all datas attached to element as handlers if any

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
$("#contributors_div").children().not("#arrow-up").remove();
var ul_data = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < CONTRIBUTORS.length; i++) {
    ul_data = ul_data + "<li><h3>" + CONTRIBUTORS[i] + "</h3></li>";
}
$("#contributors_div").append(ul_data);
```

First I remove all the content from the except(`not()`) the `#arrow-up` div and then run your loop to make a ul and then atlast append it to your div.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4594/1).

Comment: Sorry, whoever voted down please see my edit changed `html` to `append()`

Comment: Your first line will always remove the `#contributors_div`.